# Why is $E(E(X^2|\mathcal G))-E^2(E(X|\mathcal G))=EX^2-(EX)^2$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Why is $E(E(X^2|\mathcal G))-E^2(E(X|\mathcal G))=EX^2-(EX)^2$ if $X\in \mathcal F\supset \mathcal G$

I need to prove some identity but the last step is missing, I mean $X$ is not necessarily $\mathcal G$ measurable otherwise it would be obvious, can you help

Answer (score 2):

The proof rests on the fact that $\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[Y\mid\mathcal A\right]\right]= \mathbb E\left[Y\right]$ for each integrable random variable $Y$ and each sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$.

Comment: So $\mathbb E\left[Y\mid\mathcal A\right]=Y$ ?

Comment: No, you cannot deduce from the fact that two random variables have the same expectation that they are equal (for example, consider a centered non-zero random variable).

Comment: "The proof rests on the fact that..." Indeed, used twice.